# Space between parent div and child div?

Tags: html, css, border-box

**Code:**

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="box">???</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    background-color: #0000FF;
    display: block;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 600px;
}

.box {
    border: solid 20px #FF0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/5k0ddtdn/4/

I'm expecting the red border to wrap completely around the blue parent div considering this isn't a `border-box`.

Why doesn't it do that?

Comment: It's because it **isn't** `border-box` that is causing the space. It is currently `content-box` which means: _This is the default style as specified by the CSS standard. The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the padding, border or margin._ For more info see [Box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 1):

update your box like so :

```
.box {
    border: solid 20px #FF0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5k0ddtdn/9/)**

Comment: Any ideas as to why mine doesn't work? Decent solution but the border still doesn't wrap around ".wrap" at the bottom like it intuitively should.

Answer (score 1):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.box`.

```
.box {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5k0ddtdn/8/

In your code, the inner element has width 600px + 40px border, the parent element (`.wrap` has 640px in total). You need to change `box-model`, or set correct size to inner element (`width: 560px; height: 560px;`). You can remove `width` for inner element and set just `height: 560px;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5k0ddtdn/10/